# Please post a picture of the mills tonfa were supposedly used to turn

Tags: japan, china, technology, weapons

A tonfa is a forearm length club with a handle protruding sideways. A common claim is that the weapon was originally a handle used to turn millstones. [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonfa) claims that there are pictures and texts that prove the millstone story - without providing internet accessible sources

There's lot's of uncertainty regarding the origin of the Tonfa.

- "*[The Chinese and Malay words for the weapon (guai and topang respectively) literally mean crutch, which may suggest the weapon originating from the crutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonfa).*"
- There's also the story the weapon was first developed as such on Okinawa in the centuries after the Satsuma invasion, however tonfa apear to be older. It is also said that Sai (A type of truncheon) are derived from Okinawan farming implements, which appears to be completely false, so I kind of doubt any story that attests a "farming" background to weapons associated with Okinawan martial arts.

So to answer the question of whether tonfa *could* be reasonably developed from millstone handles, I want pictures and text of likely candidates for these mills and how a tonfa shaped object might fit in.

Comment: OP is trying to determine the plausibility of a historical assertion, and specifically asking for material to support the assertions on German Wikipedia.  That seems to be within the [scope we've been discussing on Meta.](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3701/1401) - specifically the verification of Wikipedia details.

Comment: Just as a bit of background, part of the foundational myth of Okinawan martial arts is that weapons were not allowed to the common people, so they had to secretly study using farm implements which could not be forbidden. There's a similar story behind the origins of the [Brazilian "dancing" martial art Capoeira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capoeira#Origins). History may not back it up, but its a good story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An article which studies the [The History of Grinding Implements for the Domestic Use in Japan](http://bigai.world.coocan.jp/msand/miwa/e_implement.html)  has several images which show [*tonfa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonfa) style parts. One style in particular can be traced to both Rome and China:

[image]

> Fig. 5 (b)　Rotary quern of Rome and China of Han Dynasty.

A hammer-shaped pestle from the same article:
[image]